# In React, how can I animate a div fading away and prevent the content below it from jumping at the end of the animation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have a div that I animate away using a fade. Upon finishing, I believe it sets `display:none` at which point, the content below it jumps up to fill the space. How can I make this more smooth? I thought maybe at the end of the animation I could insert a `visibility:hidden` div of the exact same height, and animate its height shrinking. But this feels like such a common thing to do, I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Transition the height down to zero also

Answer (score 1):

`display: none` removes the element from the DOM completely and naturally the rest of the elements will just 'jump up' up to take its place... If you don't want this you can simply set it `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0`... instead of creating a placeholder div with the same...

Comment: Regardless of whether I use a dummy or animate the original div, how can I chain the animations so that the shrinking will immediately follow the fade?

Comment: As @charliefl mentioned above you can transition the height to 0... It's a little abstract without an actual example of code...

Comment: @lowellk I meant your use case, your code... Is the animation triggered on a button click or...

Comment: I can't share my code, though it's not interesting. But it's pretty simple - there is a banner with a 'got it' link, and when you click the link, the banner goes away.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/2w2466p38n This doesn't have an onClick it's just set in an infinite loop but I think you can sort out how to add the onClick... Does that help? @lowellk